# Java API for ElasticSearch multi field search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Under an index, I have my documents with fields lets say `name` and `location`.
Now, to search all documents with `name` "Peter" and `location` "Paris".

My Java code for this is:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName);
SearchSourceBuilder builder = new SearchSourceBuilder().postFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("name", "Peter")).postFilter(QueryBuilders.termQuery("location", "Paris"));

SearchResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Above code, doesn't give me accurate result.
Could someone please help with correct approach ?

Comment: I had added the JAVA API example, did you get a chance to go through it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code, note currently you are using the [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) on `text` field, which will not allow you to do the case-insensitive match as it's not analyzed and normally used for exact searches.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index-name");
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        if (name != null) {
            MatchQueryBuilder nameMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("name", name); // replace name with `peter`
            boolQueryBuilder.should(nameMatchQueryBuilder); // change it to `must` if you want this result to be present.
        }
        if (location != null) {
            MatchQueryBuilder locationMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("location", location);
            boolQueryBuilder.should(locationMatchQueryBuilder);
        }
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.query(boolQueryBuilder);
        log.info("Search json {}", searchSourceBuilder.toString());
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = esclient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Also please notice the comments in the code, as you can see it generates [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), so if you want both terms to be present replace `boolQueryBuilder.should(nameMatchQueryBuilder);` construct with `boolQueryBuilder.must(nameMatchQueryBuilder);`

Answer (score 0):

In JSON format, your query should be like this :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "Peter"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "location": "Paris"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How would I do that in Java API ?